# yahoo gemini exception while getting jobResponse

Tags: java

I'm using Yahoo Gemini. While I'm trying to integrate an account its not happening. Actually `jobResponse` is showing `null`. Here's my code:

```
JSONObject jo1 = new JSONObject(jsonString.toString());
respKey = jo1.getJSONObject("response").getString("jobResponse");
br.close();
connection.disconnect();
return respKey;
```

At respkey its throwing an exception:

> Exception occurred in target VM: JSONObject["jobResponse"] not found.

At `jo1` its returning value as

```
jobId=132454;
status:running;
key:response;
error=null;
timesatmp:current time;
```

Comment: could you post the json?

Comment: sorry sameera I dint get you.. Actually i'm new to this so i dont have good knowledge on wt u saying..

Comment: post the json that you got in return after the network call.

Comment: (java.lang.String) "{"errors":null,"timestamp":"2016-12-28 8:43:16","response":{"jobId":13363911,"status":"running"}}"